# Ajax pulling information from second select and database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I want to have multiple drop down lists that perform a search in the database and echo the information in a table on the webpage.

From tutorials I have managed this, but only for one select choice. I am struggling to make the second drop down list refine the search conditions.

- Drop down list 1 should be the option that searches the database for the selected value.
- Drop down list 2 should add an AND condition to the sql and uses the second value to refine the search.

The code below does not pull any info from the database on change. If I remove the `AND` statement it will pull information from the database.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title> Vault of Faults-Fault Search </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css">

      <script src="dropdownfix1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id=container>

    <div id=header>
        <div id=headdiv>


          <form id=login name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
                  <fieldset class="field_set">
                  <legend>Administrator Login:</legend> <!-- legeng tage creates a header title for the fieldset box, filedset pulls all data in the tag to gether with a box around it. -->

                  UserName: <input type="text" name="username"> <br>

                  Password:<br> <input type="password" name="password"> <br>

                  <input type="submit" value="Login"> <input type="Button" onClick="parent.location='addafix.php'" Value="Add a Fix">


                  </fieldset>
                  </form>


        </div>
    </div>

      <div id=content>
        <div id=maincontent>

        <div id=select>
    <form>
        <fieldset class="field_set2">
        <legend>Quicklink Vault of Faults Search</legend>
      Product:



    <select name="Product" onchange="showUser(this.value)">

      <option value="0">Select Product</option>
      <option value="1">Merlin</option>
      <option value="2">Encoder</option>
      <option value="3">Mac Live</option>
      <option value="4">Windows Live</option>
      <option value="5">Windows S&F</option>
      <option value="6">Mac S&F</option>
      </select>

      <select name="Product_Issue" onchange="showIssue(this.value)">

      <option value="0">Select Issue</option>
      <option value="1">Preview</option>
      <option value="2">Live Reciever</option>
      <option value="3">Mac Live</option>
      <option value="4">Windows Live</option>
      <option value="5">Windows S&F</option>
      <option value="6">Mac S&F</option>
      </select>






      <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </fieldset>
  </form>


  </div>
          <div id=list>
          <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div> 
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>



  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}


function showIssue(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?p="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP:

```php
<?php

$q=$_GET["q"];
$p=$_GET["p"];                      
require 'connection.php';
mysqli_select_db($con,"Faults" );

//where statement in the sql syntax will select where in db to get infor, use AND to add another condition
$sql="SELECT Products.Product_Name, Versions.Version, Platform.Platform_Name, Issues.Issue, Issues.Sub_Issue, Issues.Fix
FROM Solutions INNER JOIN Products ON Solutions.Product = Products.Product_id
INNER JOIN Versions ON Solutions.Product_Version = Versions.Version_id
INNER JOIN Platform ON Solutions.Product_Platform = Platform.Platform_id
INNER JOIN Issues ON Solutions.Product_Issue = Issues.Issue_id
WHERE Product = '".$q."' AND Product_Issue = '".$p."'";




$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


//below is the echo statment to create the results in a table format, list collumn titles
echo "<table id=tables border='1'> 
<tr>
<th>Products</th>
<th>Version</th>
<th>Platform</th>
<th>Issue</th>
<th>Sub Issue</th>
<th>Fix</th>



</tr>";

//below is script to list reults in a table format, $row [row name on table] 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Product_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Version'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Platform_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Issue'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Sub_Issue'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"idfix.php?Fix=" . nl2br($row['Fix']) . "\">Fix</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

// below closes the coonection to mysql


?>
```

Comment: I think the issue is in the Javascript xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?p="+str,true);

Comment: you mean it's working when you remove the `AND` keyword in your query?

Comment: i have found the AND statement is fine, the issue may be on passing the information

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concat the values of the dropdownlist. Something like:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function server(aform)
     {
     var xmlhttp; 
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+ product.value +"&" +"p="+product_i.value ,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     }
    </script>
```